# Proguard keep enum constants name

Tags: java, enums, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate an enum class like this

```
enum ObfuscateMe implements Localized {

    ENUM_KEEP_A("data_a"),
    ENUM_KEEP_B("data_b");

    private String localization;

    private ObfuscateMe(String localization) {
        this.localization = localization;
    }   

    @Override
    public String getLocalization() {
        return localization;
    }

}
```

I just want to keep the enum constant name (ENUM_KEEP_A/ENUM_KEEP_B) and obfuscate everything else (field/method/interface etc..).

My proguard config look like this right now:

```
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```